# Some permission are not available in profile?

Tags: profile

When I am migration profiles from one organization to another that time I need some permission in Target organization,
but in target organization these permissions are not available.
Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make these permission available in target organization.

```
1) ManageNetwork
2) ManageCssUser
3) EditownQuota
4) ManagePartners
5) ManageSelfService
6) ManageTranslation
```

Comment: It depends on which features are enabled and which version you are deploying with. For instance the ManageTranslation permission requires the Translation workbench to be enabled in the destination org.